# new chrome version issue in cross domain request using ajax

Tags: google-chrome, jquery, post, cross-domain

In old chrome version, i can post a request to wcf rest service with jquery ajax although they are not same domain, I add CORS support to server, after I update to 30.0.1599.101 version, It does not work again. I test with rest client,safari, IE, and firefox ,they can work. in addition, Get request is still supported.
code snippet as follows,

```
function getTempValue(pointname, succeed) {

        var data = '{"pointname":"' + pointname + '"}';
        var invoker = new InterfaceInvoker("http://localhost/UCBService/UCBDemoService.svc", "GetPointValue", data, "POST");
        invoker.Invoke(succeed);
    }
function InterfaceInvoker(newUrl, newInterfaceName, newParameter, newRequestType) {
    var url, interfaceName, parameter, requestType;
    this.GetUrl = function () {
    return url;
};
this.SetUrl = function (newUrl) {
    url = newUrl || "no url setted";
};
this.GetInterfaceName = function () {
    return interfaceName;
};
this.SetInterfaceName = function (newInterfaceName) {
    interfaceName = newInterfaceName || "no interface setted";
};
this.GetParameter = function () {
    return parameter;
};
this.SetParameter = function (newParameter) {
    parameter = newParameter;
};
this.GetRequestType = function () {
    return requestType;
};
this.SetRequestType = function (newRequestType) {
    requestType = newRequestType || "no requestType setted";
};
this.SetUrl(newUrl);
this.SetInterfaceName(newInterfaceName);
this.SetParameter(newParameter);
this.SetRequestType(newRequestType);
}
InterfaceInvoker.prototype.Invoke = function (successCallBack, failureCallback) {
    var Type = this.GetRequestType(),
        Url = this.GetUrl() + "/" + this.GetInterfaceName(),
        Data = this.GetParameter(),       
        ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        DataType = "json",
        ProcessData = true;
    $.support.cors = true;
 return $.ajax({
 type: Type,
 async: "true",      
        url: Url,                       // Location of the service
        data: Data,                     //Data sent to server
        contentType: ContentType,       // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType,             //Expected data format from server
        processdata: ProcessData,       //True or False
        timeout: 3000000,                //Timeout setting 
        success: successCallBack || function () { alert("Succeded!") }, //On Successfull service call
        error: failureCallback || function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Failed!" + jqXHR.statusText); }      // When Service call fails
    });
};
```

Reponse information as follows,

```
Request URL:http://localhost/UCBService/UCBDemoService.svc/GetPointValue)
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost:51818
Referer:
    http://localhost:51818/HTMLPage1.htm
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)       Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36


Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:POST
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:1565
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 23 Oct 2013 08:01:23 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about the solution either (Stumbled upon your question while searching for a solution for my problem :D), but i have found link (http://praneeth4victory.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/405-method-not-allowed/) which leads me to think the OPTIONS-Preflight-Request is no longer optional in the new Chrome-Version but mandatory. I would try implementing an answer to the OPTIONS-Request and see if that helps.

Edit:
Yes, as it turns out this is the problem. I added

```
if request.method == "OPTIONS":
    response = Response()
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DEL")
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization')
    return response
```

To my request-handling method (Just for testing, this sure could be done nicer :D) and jQuery does not complain any longer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error recently while helping a friend. The problem is that Chrome incorrectly ignored failed pre-flight requests.  This bug originated in webkit.  However, the problem that you are having has to do with IIS 7 with .net 4.0 sending a 405 on the pre-flight OPTIONS call.  The fix for this problem is to write your own OPTIONS request handler.
This blog entry does a great job explaining it.
http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/the-cors/

Taken directly from the post:

First you need to create a class that will intercept OPTIONS and allow them to always succede
    public class CORSModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose() { }

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreSendRequestHeaders += delegate
        {
            if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                var response = context.Response;
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then you need to modify your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Authorization" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  <modules>
    <add name="CORSModule" type="CORSModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

This will intercept the OPTIONS request and return 200.  Note that it is not secure and that you should add appropriate security.  And as a final note, upgrading to .net 4.5 is considered the best fix.